# Google maps Transit duration seems to be out by anything from seconds to possibly hours

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Has anyone else noticed that the duration times for TRANSIT when requested through the directions api are incorrect?

I have made an [example fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/w2HgF/) to try and demonstrate the issue, so I can get some confirmation that it isn't just me missing something.

```
var start = 'Liverpool,England';
var end = '51.47688,-0.000329';
var request = {
    origin: start,
    destination: end,
    travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.TRANSIT,
    provideRouteAlternatives: true
};
directionsService.route(request, function (response, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
        directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
    }
});
```

There is a link in the fiddle that goes to the google maps page with the same result set to try and demonstrate the difference in the 'duration'.

It looks to me as though the wait times between connections are not being added into their calculations. So say you had three connections, each with an hour wait, the result would actually be three hours out!

I tried searching for anyone else mentioning this, but all my checks came back empty and I cannot be the only one who noticed.

Can anyone see anything wrong with my reasoning?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not seeing any difference between the fiddle and [google maps](https://maps.google.co.uk/maps?saddr=Liverpool,England&daddr=51.47688,-0.000329&dirflg=r). The fiddle gives four routes, ranging from 3:24 to 3:41. So does google maps. It looks like they've fixed your problem.

Or are you saying that they're both wrong now?